# How can I create dynamic element height on based on word count?

Tags: jquery, css

I use the following script to make the product title height bigger by clicking it when there are 6 or more words. Its working without problems when words are small but on some titles with 2-3 huge works isn't. Can we alter the code so it can always work? By pixels maybe?

JS:

```
var producttitle = jQuery(".product-view .product-shop .product-name h1");
var numWords = producttitle.text().split(" ").length;
if (numWords > 6) { jQuery(".product-view .product-name h1").css("cursor","pointer").css("cursor","hand").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('long-title');
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="product-name">
   <h1 itemprop="name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.catalog-product-view .product-name h1.long-title { 
  text-overflow: inherit; 
  white-space: inherit;  
}
.category-title h1, .product-name h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Please add code for your html element and relevant css

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want... But if it is about adjusting your title when the words are too long, consider using relative font sizes, that grows or shrinks with the container's size. Try something like `vw` or `vmin` - `font-size: 5vw`

Comment: You can use [``jQuery Bigtext Plugin``](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamically-Resize-Text-Size-To-Fit-Container-Size-jQuery-Bigtext-Plugin/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to hide some big block of text and show the rest of it on click (or hover in my example), then you could achieve that with something like this:

Your big block of text:

```
<div id="big-sentence">
    lorum ipsum dolor ismet lorum ipsum dolor ismet
 lorum ipsum dolor ismet lorum ipsum dolor 
ismet lorum ipsum dolor ismet lorum
 ipsum dolor ismet lorum ipsum 
dolor ismet lorum ipsum dolor 
ismet lorum ipsum dolor ismet 
lorum ipsum dolor ismet lorum 
ipsum dolor ismet lorum ipsum 
dolor ismet lorum ipsum dolor 
ismet lorum ipsum dolor ismet 
lorum ipsum dolor ismet lorum 
ipsum dolor ismet lorum ipsum 
dolor ismet lorum ipsum dolor ismet
</div>
```

and with css like this:

```
#big-sentence {
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#big-sentence:hover {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

The result will be like:
the normal state:

[image]

and on mouse hover:

[image]

Of course I did it on hover and you can trigger it on mouse click.